# mysqldump creates more rows than the actual range of primary key

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table that is roughly 290,000 rows long. Before backup, it probably took <200 MB. When I created a backup of this table using `mysqldump`, the backup file takes ~800 MB, and when I reload from the backup file using `mysql`, I now see that it has ~430,000 rows, way more than the original table (I am checking via HeidiSQL UI).  But if I do a query on the total range of the primary key, it is the same as the old table (~290,000). What could have possibly gone wrong?

Here is the CREATE code for the particular table in concern. It is just a list of variables (of DECIMAL type)

```
    CREATE TABLE `ciceroout` (
    `runID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `IterationNum` DECIMAL(20,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IterationCount` DECIMAL(20,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `RunningCounter` DECIMAL(20,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    \* more 100 variables like this *\
    PRIMARY KEY (`runID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=287705
;
```

EDIT: Here is the actual dump and restore commands I used. Our database has six tables, and I already dumped one table so here I am dumping the remaining five tables.

dump tables :

```
 mysqldump -u root --single-transaction=true --verbose -p [dbname] --ignore-table=[dbname].images > \path\[backupname].sql
```

restore tables (after dropping the original database, and starting an empty one):

```
mysql -u root -p [db name] < \path\[backupname].sql
```

and here is what I see on HeidiSQL UI
[image]

Comment: You didn't tell us how you backed it up. You didn't tell us how you restored it. You didn't tell us how you determined the number of rows. You didn't tell us how you checked to find fewer.

Comment: @symcbean, I did mention using mysqldump, MySQL, and using HeidiSQL for the tasks you mentioned. Do you want the codes verbatim?

Comment: @symcbean - Show us the arguments to `mysqldump`.  Show us the query to discover that there are 430K rows.

Comment: @RickJames, please see the new materials under EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wonder about the big export file: thats normal. 
The data is stored in a human readable format (SQL), while the actual data on the tablespace is stored in a much more effficient data structure (B+Tree)

Regarding the table statistics HeidiSQL is showing you:
 For InnoDB, the "number of rows" statistic is just an *approximation*.

The result of `COUNT(*)` gives you the real amount of rows, which is matching the original, right?

The approximation will change over time and get better as you start working with the data.

The MySQL manual page for [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html) states:

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
>   exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
>   an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40
>   to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
>   count.

Comment: Then is the extra number of rows like a pre-allocated space? As you said, the result of COUNT indeed matches the actual size of the data. It is still weird that the disk space occupied by the backup produced by mysqldump is much larger than the original size of the data befor backup.

Comment: "disk space used" is a completely different thing. I mean, usually you only have one big table space (one big file) that gets extended by XXX MB every time its nearly full. How are you sure, that your data was only <200MB on disk before? table statistics? ;^)

Comment: Yes, that was the table statistics I saw on HeidiSQL before I began mysqldump...We just ran several data acquisition and saw that the row number has increased one by one, instead of decreasing. So the "approximation" should eventually converge to the correct number of data rows after enough data acquisition?

Comment: Yes. Restarting the server after that "initial load" might also help. A `SELECT * FROM tbl` should also do the trick. Or just check if your data is there and carry on. (thats would I would do)

Comment: @IamAStudent if you wonder about the big export file: thats normal. The data is stored in a human readable format (SQL), while the actual data on the tablespace is stored in a much more effficient data structure (B+Tree)

Comment: We did SELECT * FROM table multiple times, and checked that indeed there are only ~280,000 data as we expected, but the number of rows and the disk space occupied has not changed. I guess I will wait for a day to see they eventually change.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are dumping an `INT`, which is a 4-byte quantity in the database.

```
Value = 1 -- dump contains ...,1,... -- effectively 2 bytes.
value = -1222333444 -- dump contains ...,-1222333444,... -- 12 bytes
```

With those examples, you see that an `INT` can take between half as much space and 3-times as much space when dumped.  (Other datatypes lead to other examples.)

The "280K rows" is exact and won't change until you `INSERT`/`DELETE` rows.  The "430K" is, as already mentioned, an approximation.

The actual disk space may have increased or decreased slightly after dumping and loading.  This is due to a large number of factors.

We just have to live with these non-very-important inconsistencies.

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` is another way to see the disk space.

I think of "counters" as being whole numbers.  Is there some reason for having 10 decimal places on this:

```
RunningCounter` DECIMAL(20,10)
```

Changing all of those to `INT` would shrink each column from 10 bytes to 4 bytes.  This would cut the disk utilization in half.

Comment: Dear @RickJames, thank you for the example. Am I correct in understanding that (note I have little CS background) the two values present effectively 2 bytes and 12  bytes because they are characters converted from INT? Regarding "counter" as "DECIMAL", I agree with you and it is a poor design choice (not by me). I just finished an experiment where I took more than 300 new images, but the "approximation" is still pretty bad, staying at 430K. I may try closing and re-opening the server tomorrow and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @IamAStudent - Convert to INT - yes.  The 430K vs 280K discrepancy - Live with it; it will not necessarily change.